# Oracle not returning any data for yesterdays hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT d_dtm,
       BTS_ID,
       CASE WHEN D_DTM = (D_DTM-24/24)
            THEN sum(V_ATT_CNT)
       END AS "LASTATT",

       sum(V_ATT_CNT) as "V_ATT_CNT",

       CASE WHEN D_DTM = D_DTM
            THEN sum(V_ATT_CNT)
       END AS "ATT"

 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI

WHERE to_date(D_DTM, 'DD/MM/yyyy') >=
      (SELECT TO_DATE(max(D_DTM),'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI)-2

GROUP BY d_dtm,
        BTS_ID

HAVING CASE WHEN D_DTM = (D_DTM-24/24)
           THEN sum(V_ATT_CNT)                
       END > 0
```

But it is not returning any results because of the "having" clause. I know it should return results because all I want it to do is in one column have the V_ATT for the current time period, and in the 2nd column, have the V_ATT 24 hours ago. I've checked the data and I should get results back but can't seem to figure out why this is not working...

Comment: This condition `D_DTM = (D_DTM-24/24)` is always FALSE.

Comment: Your query is wrong and hard to read. You need to add sample data.

Comment: What datatype is `D_DTM`?

Comment: You're treating D_DTM as a date in some places and as a character string in others. If it's a DD/MM/YYYY character string you cannot MAX() it nor subtract from it. If it's a DATE then you don't need to convert it to a date with TO_DATE().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the query using a with statement and two queries. Works pretty fast and gives me the correct results.

```
   WITH FRST
        AS (  SELECT D_DTM,
                     BSM_NM,
                     SUM (V_ATT_CNT) AS "V_ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (V_CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "V_CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (V_DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "V_DRP_CALL_CNT",
                     SUM (D_ATT_CNT) AS "D_ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (D_CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "D_CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (D_DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "D_DRP_CALL_CNT"
                FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI
               WHERE D_DTM >=
                        (SELECT MAX (D_DTM) - NUMTODSINTERVAL (12, 'HOUR')
                           FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI)
            GROUP BY D_DTM, BSM_NM),
        LST
        AS (  SELECT D_DTM,
                     BSM_NM,
                     SUM (V_ATT_CNT) AS "V_ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (V_CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "V_CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (V_DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "V_DRP_CALL_CNT",
                     SUM (D_ATT_CNT) AS "D_ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (D_CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "D_CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (D_DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "D_DRP_CALL_CNT"
                FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI
               WHERE D_DTM >=
                        (SELECT MAX (D_DTM) - NUMTODSINTERVAL (48, 'HOUR')
                           FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI)
            GROUP BY D_DTM, BSM_NM),
        EVDOLST
        AS (  SELECT D_DTM,
                     BSM_NM,
                     SUM (ATT_CNT) AS "ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "DRP_CALL_CNT"
                FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_EVDO_FA_LVL_KPI
               WHERE D_DTM >=
                        (SELECT MAX (D_DTM) - NUMTODSINTERVAL (48, 'HOUR')
                           FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_EVDO_FA_LVL_KPI)
            GROUP BY D_DTM, BSM_NM),
        EVDOFRST
        AS (  SELECT D_DTM,
                     BSM_NM,
                     SUM (ATT_CNT) AS "ATT_CNT",
                     SUM (CUST_BLK_CNT) AS "CUST_BLK_CNT",
                     SUM (DRP_CALL_CNT) AS "DRP_CALL_CNT"
                FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_EVDO_FA_LVL_KPI
               WHERE D_DTM >=
                        (SELECT MAX (D_DTM) - NUMTODSINTERVAL (12, 'HOUR')
                           FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_EVDO_FA_LVL_KPI)
            GROUP BY D_DTM, BSM_NM)
   SELECT t1.D_DTM,
          t1.BSM_NM,
          t2.V_ATT_CNT AS "LASTV_ATTCNT",
          t2.V_CUST_BLK_CNT AS "LASTV_BLKCNT",
          t2.V_DRP_CALL_CNT AS "LASTV_DRPCNT",
          t1.V_ATT_CNT AS "V_ATT_CNT",
          t1.V_CUST_BLK_CNT AS "V_CUST_BLK_CNT",
          t1.V_DRP_CALL_CNT AS "V_DRP_CALL_CNT",
          t2.D_ATT_CNT AS "LASTD_ATTCNT",
          t2.D_CUST_BLK_CNT AS "LASTD_BLKCNT",
          t2.D_DRP_CALL_CNT AS "LASTD_DRPCNT",
          t1.D_ATT_CNT AS "D_ATT_CNT",
          t1.D_CUST_BLK_CNT AS "D_CUST_BLK_CNT",
          t1.D_DRP_CALL_CNT AS "D_DRP_CALL_CNT",
          t3.ATT_CNT AS "EVDO_ATTCNT",
          t3.CUST_BLK_CNT AS "EVDO_BLKCNT",
          t3.DRP_CALL_CNT AS "EVDO_DRPCNT",
          t4.ATT_CNT AS "EVDO_LASTATTCNT",
          t4.CUST_BLK_CNT AS "EVDO_LASTBLKCNT",
          t4.DRP_CALL_CNT AS "EVDO_LASTDRPCNT"
     FROM FRST t1
          INNER JOIN LST t2
             ON     t1.BSM_NM = t2.BSM_NM
                AND t1.D_DTM - NUMTODSINTERVAL (24, 'HOUR') = t2.D_DTM
          LEFT OUTER JOIN EVDOLST t4
             ON     t1.BSM_NM = t4.BSM_NM
                AND t1.D_DTM - NUMTODSINTERVAL (24, 'HOUR') = t4.D_DTM
          LEFT OUTER JOIN EVDOFRST t3
             ON t1.BSM_NM = t3.BSM_NM AND t1.D_DTM = t3.D_DTM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you subtotal (group by) D_DTM, you get one row per date.  If you want to compare two dates with each other in the *same row* you need to do one of two things: either a subquery, or a window function like lag/lead.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT d_dtm,
   BTS_ID,
   lag(sum(V_ATT_CNT), 1) over (partition by bts_id order by d_dtm) 
      AS "LASTATT",
   sum(V_ATT_CNT) as "V_ATT_CNT"

 FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI

  WHERE to_date(D_DTM, 'DD/MM/yyyy') >=
     (SELECT TO_DATE(max(D_DTM),'DD/MM/YYYY') 
         FROM DMSN.DS3R_FH_1XRTT_FA_LVL_KPI)-2

 GROUP BY d_dtm,
    BTS_ID
```

Note that the `partition by` columns in the lag/over is a *subset* of the `group by` columns.

Comment: I don't think the partition by will work in my case since partition by looks at the count of rows...